# Finding $y$ if more than two $x$ satisfy absolute value equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Consider the equation:
$$y=\big||x|-1\big|$$
In what interval will $y$ lie, if more than two values of $x$ should satisfy the above equation?

**My work:**

I was able to solve this by plotting the graph of the given function. From the graph, we can identify that $y \in (0,1]$. However, I wish to avoid using graphical solutions such as this.

I’m unsure how to solve this algebraically. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not difficult to write down the inverse explicitly.

Comment: How exactly do we write down its inverse? I’m a novice at such problems.

Comment: Look at the 4 equations $y=\pm ( \pm x-1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
||x|-1| = y &\to |x| - 1 = \pm y \\
&\to |x| = 1 \pm y \\
&\to x = \pm1 \pm y, \
\end{align}
so we automatically have at least two solutions, and potentially as many as four. Now the first equation, $$|x| - 1 = \pm y,$$ has both signs achievable as distinct solutions iff $0 < y \leq 1$, since $|x| - 1 \geq -1$. So this condition, $y \in (0, 1]$, is also what is needed to guarantee three or more distinct solutions.